# pip install packages using sudo command

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to install a virtualenv package -

First, I directly try to install but get permission denied error
Second, the same user(has sudo access) with sudo command tells pip2.7 is not a command.

why is it pip2.7 is visible for the user but not using the sudo command?

```
[lduser@q-dev-5461-4f3c-9d98-7af28dfc3ec6 bin]$ pip2.7 install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-14.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 731, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 841, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1040, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 343, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 321, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.pyc'



[duser@q-dev-5461-4f3c-9d98-7af28dfc3ec6 bin]$ sudo pip2.7 install virtualenv
sudo: pip2.7: command not found
```

Comment: As stated in the error message `pip2.7` isn't available as a command. So _how_ did you call `pip` to install other Python packages? On my system I have access to `pip` for Python 2 and `pip3` for Python 3. You can try this by looking for the paths of those commands by using `which pip` and `which pip3`.

Comment: how can it find when I dont enter "sudo" before it?

Comment: Seems like the $PATH for the su user is incorrect

Comment: Not a programming question, belongs to **super user** or **Unix & Linux**.

Comment: Do you have `pip2.7` as a user alias? If so, that's the issue. Add the same `alias` to the shell config of su.

Comment: The @PATH is not set for the su user..If i give full path, it works..Thanks everyone

Comment: sudo /usr/bin/pip{version} install virtualenv